Internal private React library
Is it possible to set up a library in React without publishing it on npm?
I need to remove some components of one application to a separate library so it could be used in two different internal projects, but all the guides I found about making react libraries ended up publishing the library on npm. Is there any way of sharing this code without being a copy and paste of code, but at the same time, not having to publish it on a public network?

This question is similar to: How to specify local modules as npm package dependencies. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, you can avoid publishing on npm by installing the package directly from a GitHub or GitLab private repository. Simply use the command: npm install <git remote url>.
